# Android SQL only returns one column

Tags: java, android, sql

I got a SQL database containing the following layout:

[image: SQL Table]

The table is called `messages` with around 5 columns.

I created an Cursor which should get all values from both columns using this:

```
public List<String> getContacts(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    List<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT `from`,`to` FROM messages";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            List.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return List;
}
```

And here I add the values to a ListView:

```
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(
            this.getApplicationContext());

    newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    List<String> all = dbHelper.getContacts(newDB);
    if (all.size() > 0) // check if list contains items.
    {

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, all));

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(ConversationsList.this, "No items to display", 1000)
                .show();
    }
```

And yes values gets added, but only the `me` which is very weird. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Solved it by changing this:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                List.add(cursor.getString(0));
                List.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

To:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                List.add(cursor.getString(0));
                List.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

Comment: "Android SQL only returns one column" : you're only selecting data from one column here cursor.getString(1). Do you mean only 1 row is being returned with 1 column value?

Comment: @derpyderp no, several rows but one column value.

Comment: @SarathChandra yes indeed, sounds logic! :) is there anyway to get them all?

Comment: List.add(cursor.getString(1)+"--"+cursor.getString(2)+''--"+cursor.getString(3)+...); to get a -- delimited result

Comment: When I change to cursor.getString(0), I indeed get the first column, but how to get them all?

Comment: Ok, so you're only selecting one column (cursor.getString(1)) which is the second column as the index starts at 0. To get more columns you need to select them, for example: cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2). It would make sense to create a 'Contact' object and set each value, so for example contact.setName(cursor.getString(1)), contact.setNumber(cursor.getString(2)). You would also need a custom adapter to display the data instead of using a simple ArrayAdapter.

Comment: @SarathChandra, now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `List<String> List` and

```
do {
    List.add(cursor.getString(1));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

are causing the problem.

If you cannot alter the List type,

```
do {
     List.add(
            cursor.getString(1) +","
            cursor.getString(1) +","
            ...
            +cursor.getString(n));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

will fetch comma delimited values of each record into the String. You can split the string and use the values individually.

Comment: do you also know how to remove the value 'me' from the Cursor? And also scan if there are duplicates?